# Forking a Mainnet is showing `Unable to launch local RPC client` error

Tags: brownie

while running the command `brownie console --network mainnet-fork` I am getting the following error:

```
RPCProcessError: Unable to launch local RPC client.
Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

I have exported my `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID` and using the `nvm version 16.13.2`.
Can't seem to figure out a way to fork the mainnet in brownie

Comment: testing and using brownie locally is working just fine

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you fix it?